# T-SQL using SUM for a running total

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a simple table with some dummy data setup like:

```
|id|user|value|
---------------
 1  John   2
 2  Ted    1
 3  John   4
 4  Ted    2
```

I can select a running total by executing the following sql(MSSQL 2008) statement:

```
SELECT a.id, a.user, a.value, SUM(b.value) AS total
FROM table a INNER JOIN table b
ON a.id >= b.id
AND a.user = b.user
GROUP BY a.id, a.user, a.value
ORDER BY a.id
```

This will give me results like:

```
|id|user|value|total|
---------------------
 1  John   2     2
 3  John   4     6
 2  Ted    1     1
 4  Ted    2     3
```

Now is it possible to only retrieve the most recent rows for each user? So the result would be:

```
|id|user|value|total|
---------------------
 3  John   4     6
 4  Ted    2     3
```

Am I going about this the right way? any suggestions or a new path to follow would be great!

Comment: Are you only interested in the final result, or do you need the running total as well?  Are you storing that running total somewhere already, or are you using it Only to generate your final result?  *[Your final result can be more effectively created without using a running total.  But, if you already have the running total stored somewhere, for other reasons, it can certainly be used.]*

Comment: You swithced your accepted answer to improve performance, but you haven't responded to my query above.  Do note that you can improve performance by ***not*** using the running total method.  Would that be of interest to you, or do you need all the results in the running total *as well*?

Comment: Hi Dems, I was busily working away and missed your comment. I'm only after the total and the associated user, so yes I am interested in improved performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
;with cte as 
     (SELECT a.id, a.[user], a.value, SUM(b.value) AS total
    FROM users a INNER JOIN users b
    ON a.id >= b.id
    AND a.[user] = b.[user]
    GROUP BY a.id, a.[user], a.value
     ),
cte1 as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [user] 
                         order by total desc) as row_num
         from cte)
select  id,[user],value,total from cte1 where row_num=1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4aede/1)

Comment: @Joe G Joseph, it looks like the link to the SQL Fiddle is broken.

Answer (score 9):

No join is needed, you can speed up the query this way:

```
select id, [user], value, total
from
(
  select id, [user], value, 
  row_number() over (partition by [user] order by id desc) rn, 
  sum(value) over (partition by [user]) total
from users
) a
where rn = 1
```

Comment: this can be speeded up further by explicitly stating the additional arguments to the over clause of `SUM OVER`

Answer (score 1):

add where statement:

```
select * from
(
your select statement
) t

where t.id in (select max(id) from table group by user)
```

also you can use this query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.user, a.value, 

(select max(b.value) from table b where b.user=a.user) AS total

FROM table a 

where a.id in (select max(id) from table group by user)

ORDER BY a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a right join would perform better than nested select.

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT MAX(id), [user], MAX(value), SUM(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY [user]
```

Comment: But max(id) and max(value) can be from different original table rows.

Comment: -1 : This is an oversimplified approach that simply does not work correctly.  You can't assume that MAX(id) and MAX(value) give results from the same input row.

Comment: You are right, I realized after posting. But still, a smart right join would perform better than nested select.

Answer (score 0):

Compatible with SQL Server 2008 or later

```
DECLARE @AnotherTbl TABLE
    (
        id           INT
      , somedate     DATE
      , somevalue    DECIMAL(18, 4)
      , runningtotal DECIMAL(18, 4)
    )

INSERT INTO @AnotherTbl
    (
        id
      , somedate
      , somevalue
      , runningtotal
    )
SELECT  LEDGER_ID
      , LL.LEDGER_DocDate
      , LL.LEDGER_Amount
      , NULL
FROM    ACC_Ledger LL
ORDER BY LL.LEDGER_DocDate

DECLARE @RunningTotal DECIMAL(18, 4)
SET @RunningTotal = 0

UPDATE  @AnotherTbl
SET @RunningTotal=runningtotal = @RunningTotal + somevalue
FROM    @AnotherTbl

SELECT  *
FROM    @AnotherTbl
```