# Trying avoid using cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been given a query and trying to figure out a way to remove the cursor yet maintaining functionality, because the starting table can get into the millions of rows.

Example of data in table:

```
ID   DollarValue  Month     RowNumber
1     $10         1/1/2014  1
1     $15         2/1/2014  2
1    -$40         3/1/2014  3
1     $50         4/1/2014  4
2    -$11         1/1/2014  1
2     $11         2/1/2014  2
2     $5          3/1/2014  3
```

Expected results:

```
ID   DollarValue  Month     RowNumber  TestVal
1     $10         1/1/2014  1           1 
1     $15         2/1/2014  2           0
1    -$40         3/1/2014  3          -1
1     $50         4/1/2014  4           1
2    -$11         1/1/2014  1          -1
2     $11         2/1/2014  2           0
2     $5          3/1/2014  3           1
```

Here is the logic (pseudocode)that happens inside the cursor:

```
If a @ID <> @LastId AND @Month <> @LastMonth
  Set @RunningTotal = @DollarValue
  Set @LastMonth = '12/31/2099'
  Set @LastID = @ID
  Set @TestVal = Sign(@DollarValue)
Else
  If Sign(@RunningTotal) = Sign(@RunningTotal + @DollarValue)
    Set @TestVal = 0
Else
   Set @TestVal = Sign(@DollarValue)

Set @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + @DollarValue
```

Any idea how I can change this to set based?

Comment: Have you looked into Recursive CTEs?

Comment: What does this ultimately do with `@RunningTotal` and `@TestVal`?Does it write to another table? Update something? It would be easier to come up with an equivalent if we knew what the end goal was.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981979/t-sql-using-sum-for-a-running-total

Comment: Ann it does write to another table that is basically the previous table with the addition of the TestVal column. Running total is only used to see if the sign of the aggregated dollar amounts changes to know what to set TestVal to for that row.

Comment: I am totally confident that this cursor could be replaced with a setbased approach. I am also totally confident that without more details (like all the code and table structures) nobody can do much to help.

Comment: HLGEM Not sure why I just got a downvote, but I'm not just looking for a running total, so that post doesn't answer my question.  I do have a running total, but it's the change in the signs i'm interested in and the total is just part of how that is calculated.  I looked at using a cte already, but couldn't figure out how to set the TestVal each time the sign changed in the running total.

Comment: Join the table to itself on ID and RowNumber-1, and you have 'current' and 'next' records on one line and use a CASE statement to work out what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the windowed version of `SUM` to calculate running totals:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT ID, DollarValue, Month, RowNumber,
          SUM ( DollarValue ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RowNumber) as RunningTotal
   FROM #mytable
)
SELECT C1.ID, C1.DollarValue, C1.Month, C1.RowNumber,
       CASE WHEN C1.RowNumber = 1 THEN SIGN(C1.DollarValue)
            WHEN SIGN(C1.RunningTotal) = SIGN(C2.RunningTotal) THEN 0
            ELSE SIGN(C1.RunningTotal) 
       END AS TestVal        
FROM CTE AS C1
LEFT JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C1.ID = C2.ID AND C1.RowNumber = C2.RowNumber + 1
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` on `RowNumber` you can get the previous record and compare the current running total with the previous one. Then use a simple `CASE` to apply rules pertinent to changes in `SIGN` of running total.

[SQL FIDDLE Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d40ce/1)

P.S. It seems the above solution wont work in versions prior to SQL Server 2012. In this case the running total calculation inside the `CTE` has to be replaced by the "conventional" version.

Answer (score 2):

This is 2008 solution

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
  AA.[ID]
 ,AA.[Month]
 ,AA.[RowNumber]
 ,AA.[DollarValue]
 ,SIGN(SUM(BB.[DollarValue])) AS RunTotalSign

FROM YourTable AS AA
LEFT JOIN YourTable AS BB
       ON (AA.[ID] = BB.[ID] AND BB.[RowNumber] <= AA.[RowNumber])
GROUP BY  AA.[ID],AA.[Month],AA.[DollarValue],AA.[RowNumber])
)

SELECT 
  AA.[ID]
 ,AA.[Month]
 ,AA.[RowNumber]
 ,AA.[DollarValue]
 ,CASE WHEN AA.RunTotalSign = CC.RunTotalSign Then 0
       ELSE AA.RunTotalSign
       END
  AS TestVal
FROM CTE AS AA
LEFT JOIN CTE AS CC
       ON (AA.[ID] = CC.[ID] AND AA.[RowNumber] = CC.[RowNumber]+1)
```